# the seven number is automatically pressed how resolve it

Tags: windows-7, windows, login, virus

I started my laptop some few minute log in screen displayed and automatically  7 number is pressed more than 20 times. at this time i cant type 7 number.
is a virus??

Comment: Could be a simple hardware issue. Is your keyboard ok? Key not pressed or any liquidsin it?

Answer (score 1):

Check your keyboard. Most likely there's a problem with your 7 key(s). Maybe it's stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely an hardware issue and that means it is not a virus(software).

Take it to a repair shop, you might have to clean up the keyboard or replace it totally.

Before doing that, you may want to do a restart and then check if the key or other keys are stuck.